# How to Drag-Drop File onto Chrome Extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm creating a chrome extension that will you to drop a file onto the extension pop-up and have that file emailed to an address that's been pre-set. I'm struggling to find information of how I can integrate the email extension with the drag and drop feature of chrome.

Is there a specific event, request or API I have to use for this ?

Comment: There's no specific API for extensions. Use the drag'n'drop [examples for web pages](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bjavascript%5d%20drag%20drop%20input%20file&searchOn=3).

Comment: [Work with files > Open files in an extension using drag and drop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Working_with_files#open_files_in_an_extension_using_drag_and_drop)